# how to test if all the markers have been loaded in google map?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-markers

I need to use some kind of progress bar or wheel etc because i have a lot of markers and its taking some time to load all of them. I would like to use an animated image like loading or wheel etc as background to the map-canvas to show the progress..
i need to test if all the markers have been loaded..how do i do that?
If i can do that, i can have map background as the progress bar icon until all markers are loaded and then once they are all loaded, hide the progress bar icon or whee? Is this even a good idea??

```
var geocoder;
          var map;
          function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.095287, -79.3185139);
            var myOptions = {
              maxZoom: 14,
              zoom: 9,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                myOptions);
            createOverlay();
           }

        function codeAddress() {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}); 
            $('.LocationAddress').each(function() {
                var addy = $(this).text();
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addy}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            map: map,               
                            title:addy,
                        });

                     //Adding a click event to the marker 
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
                        infowindow.setContent('<div id=\"infowindow\" style=" height:100px;>'
                                                +'<div id=\"LeftInfo\">'+ "Hello World!"
                                                +'</div>'+'</div>'); 
                        infowindow.open(map, this); 
                    });  
                 }  
                });//Geocoder END

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consult the control, code, and examples for a [Google Maps API V3 Progress Bar](http://www.basicslabs.com/Projects/progressBar/).  It seems to do what you want, although you may have some additional complexity since you're letting people enter their own address points for the markers.